# Google Colab keras Sequential model returns an empty history.history object "{}"

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory

I am having a hard time with google colab and a Keras model that I train. I am using all kind of magic tricks like Tensorboard, HParams, callbacks, etc.

Initially, excuse me for posting code and screenshots only and not data. Since the code posted runs successfully on my local machine and not on colab I am guessing that this is not due to data error but rather code error.

- My local machine TF version: 2.1.0
- Colab's TF version: 2.2.0

Below there is my code.

**libraries**

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_addons as tfa
import tensorflow_docs as tfdocs #!pip install git+https://github.com/tensorflow/docs
import tensorflow_docs.plots as tfplots
import tensorflow_docs.modeling as tfmodel

from tensorflow.keras import layers, regularizers, models
from tensorflow.keras import models
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, EarlyStopping
from tensorflow.keras.utils import model_to_dot, plot_model
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model, model_from_json

%load_ext tensorboard
from tensorboard.plugins.hparams import api as hp

import keras.backend as K
from tensorflow import keras
```

**Callbacks**

```py
def callback(folder_path, saved_model_name, logdir, hparams):
    
    # Initialize parameters
    monitor_metric = 'val_loss'
    minimum_delta = 0.1
    patience_limit = 1
    verbose_value = 1
    mode_value = 'min'
    weights_fname = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), '{0}/{1}.h5'.format(folder_path, saved_model_name))
    print(weights_fname)
    
    # Initialize callbacks
    callbacks = [
        
        EarlyStopping(monitor=monitor_metric,
                      min_delta=minimum_delta,
                      patience=patience_limit,
                      verbose=verbose_value,
                      mode=mode_value,
                      restore_best_weights=True),

        ModelCheckpoint(filepath=weights_fname,
                        monitor=monitor_metric,
                        verbose=verbose_value,
                        save_best_only=True,
                        save_weights_only=True),

        tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(logdir),
        
        hp.KerasCallback(logdir, hparams)
    ]
    
    return callbacks
```

**Hyper parameters**

```py
HP_HIDDEN_UNITS = hp.HParam('batch_size', hp.Discrete([32, 64, 128]))
HP_EMBEDDING_DIM = hp.HParam('embedding_dim', hp.Discrete([100, 200, 300]))
HP_LEARNING_RATE = hp.HParam('learning_rate', hp.Discrete([0.001, 0.01, 0.1])) # Adam default: 0.001, SGD default: 0.01, RMSprop default: 0.001
HP_DECAY_STEPS_MULTIPLIER = hp.HParam('decay_steps_multiplier', hp.Discrete([100, 1000]))

METRIC_ACCURACY = 'accuracy'
```

**create and fit the model function**

```py
def create_fit_keras_model(hparams,
                           version_data_control,
                           optimizer_name,
                           validation_method,
                           callbacks,
                           folder_path,
                           optimizer_version = None):

    sentenceLength_actors = X_train_seq_actors.shape[1]
    vocab_size_frequent_words_actors = len(actors_tokenizer.word_index)
    
    sentenceLength_plot = X_train_seq_plot.shape[1]
    vocab_size_frequent_words_plot = len(plot_tokenizer.word_index)
    
    sentenceLength_features = X_train_seq_features.shape[1]
    vocab_size_frequent_words_features = len(features_tokenizer.word_index)
    
    sentenceLength_reviews = X_train_seq_reviews.shape[1]
    vocab_size_frequent_words_reviews = len(reviews_tokenizer.word_index)
    
    model = keras.Sequential(name='MultyInput_Keras_Classification_model_{0}dim_{1}batchsize_{2}lr_{3}decaymultiplier_{4}'.format(hparams[HP_EMBEDDING_DIM], hparams[HP_HIDDEN_UNITS],
                                                                                                                                  hparams[HP_LEARNING_RATE], hparams[HP_DECAY_STEPS_MULTIPLIER],
                                                                                                                                  version_data_control))
    actors = keras.Input(shape=(sentenceLength_actors,), name='actors_input')
    plot = keras.Input(shape=(sentenceLength_plot,), name='plot_input')
    features = keras.Input(shape=(sentenceLength_features,), name='features_input')
    reviews = keras.Input(shape=(sentenceLength_reviews,), name='reviews_input')
    
    emb1 = layers.Embedding(input_dim = vocab_size_frequent_words_actors + 2,
                            output_dim = hparams[HP_EMBEDDING_DIM],
                            embeddings_initializer = 'uniform',
                            mask_zero = True,
                            input_length = sentenceLength_actors,
                            name="actors_embedding_layer")(actors)
    
    encoded_layer1 = layers.GlobalMaxPooling1D(name="globalmaxpooling_actors_layer")(emb1)
    
    emb2 = layers.Embedding(input_dim = vocab_size_frequent_words_plot + 2,
                            output_dim = hparams[HP_EMBEDDING_DIM],
                            embeddings_initializer = 'uniform',
                            mask_zero = True,
                            input_length = sentenceLength_plot,
                            name="plot_embedding_layer")(plot)
    
    encoded_layer2 = layers.GlobalMaxPooling1D(name="globalmaxpooling_plot_summary_Layer")(emb2)

    emb3 = layers.Embedding(input_dim = vocab_size_frequent_words_features + 2,
                            output_dim = hparams[HP_EMBEDDING_DIM],
                            embeddings_initializer = 'uniform',
                            mask_zero = True,
                            input_length = sentenceLength_features,
                            name="features_embedding_layer")(features)
    
    encoded_layer3 = layers.GlobalMaxPooling1D(name="globalmaxpooling_movie_features_layer")(emb3)
    
    emb4 = layers.Embedding(input_dim = vocab_size_frequent_words_reviews + 2,
                            output_dim = hparams[HP_EMBEDDING_DIM],
                            embeddings_initializer = 'uniform',
                            mask_zero = True,
                            input_length = sentenceLength_reviews,
                            name="reviews_embedding_layer")(reviews)
    
    encoded_layer4 = layers.GlobalMaxPooling1D(name="globalmaxpooling_user_reviews_layer")(emb4)
    
    merged = layers.concatenate([encoded_layer1, encoded_layer2, encoded_layer3, encoded_layer4], axis=-1)

    dense_layer_1 = layers.Dense(hparams[HP_HIDDEN_UNITS],
                                 kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(neural_network_parameters['l2_regularization']),
                                 activation=neural_network_parameters['dense_activation'],
                                 name="1st_dense_hidden_layer_concatenated_inputs")(merged)
    
    layers.Dropout(neural_network_parameters['dropout_rate'])(dense_layer_1)
    
    output_layer = layers.Dense(y_train.shape[1], 
                                activation=neural_network_parameters['output_activation'],
                                name='output_layer')(dense_layer_1)

    model = keras.Model(inputs=[actors, plot, features, reviews], outputs=output_layer, name='MultyInput_Keras_Classification_model_{0}dim_{1}batchsize_{2}lr_{3}decaymultiplier_{4}'.format(hparams[HP_EMBEDDING_DIM], 
                                                                                                                                                                                             hparams[HP_HIDDEN_UNITS],
                                                                                                                                                                                             hparams[HP_LEARNING_RATE], 
                                                                                                                                                                                             hparams[HP_DECAY_STEPS_MULTIPLIER],
                                                                                                                                                                                             version_data_control))
    print(model.summary())
    
    if optimizer_name=="adam" and optimizer_version is None:
        
        optimizer = optimizer_adam_v2(hparams[HP_LEARNING_RATE], hparams[HP_DECAY_STEPS_MULTIPLIER], X_train_seq_actors.shape[0], optimizer_parameters['validation_split_ratio'], hparams[HP_HIDDEN_UNITS])
        
    elif optimizer_name=="sgd" and optimizer_version is None:
        
        optimizer = optimizer_sgd_v1(hparams[HP_LEARNING_RATE])
        
    elif optimizer_name=="rmsprop" and optimizer_version is None:
        
        optimizer = optimizer_rmsprop_v1(hparams[HP_LEARNING_RATE])

    model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,
                  loss=neural_network_parameters['model_loss'],
                  metrics=[neural_network_parameters['model_metric']])
    
    plot_model(model, to_file=os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'model_one/network_structure_multy_input_keras_model_{0}.png'.format(version_data_control)))
    
    start_time = time.time()
    
    if validation_method=="validation_split":
        
        model.fit([X_train_seq_actors, X_train_seq_plot, X_train_seq_features, X_train_seq_reviews],
                  y_train,
                  steps_per_epoch=int(np.ceil((X_train_seq_actors.shape[0]*optimizer_parameters['validation_split_ratio'])//hparams[HP_HIDDEN_UNITS])),
                  epochs=fit_parameters["epoch"],
                  verbose=fit_parameters["verbose_fit"],
                  batch_size=hparams[HP_HIDDEN_UNITS],
                  validation_split=fit_parameters['validation_data_ratio'],
                  callbacks=callbacks)
        
    elif validation_method=="validation_data":
        
        model.fit([X_train_seq_actors, X_train_seq_plot, X_train_seq_features, X_train_seq_reviews], 
                  y_train,
                  steps_per_epoch=int(np.ceil((X_train_seq_actors.shape[0]*optimizer_parameters['validation_split_ratio'])//hparams[HP_HIDDEN_UNITS])),
                  epochs=fit_parameters["epoch"],
                  verbose=fit_parameters["verbose_fit"],
                  batch_size=hparams[HP_HIDDEN_UNITS],
                  validation_data=([X_test_seq_actors, X_test_seq_plot, X_test_seq_features, X_test_seq_reviews], y_test),
                  callbacks=callbacks)
    
    #save the model
    save_model(model, folder_path, "multi_input_keras_model_{0}dim_{1}batchsize_{2}lr_{3}decaymultiplier_{4}".format(str(hparams[HP_EMBEDDING_DIM]), str(hparams[HP_HIDDEN_UNITS]), str(hparams[HP_LEARNING_RATE]), str(hparams[HP_DECAY_STEPS_MULTIPLIER]), version_data_control))

    elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
    
    print("\nTraining time of the multi-input keras model has finished. Duration {} secs".format(format_timespan(elapsed_time)))
    
    _, accuracy = model.evaluate([X_test_seq_actors, X_test_seq_plot, X_test_seq_features, X_test_seq_reviews], y_test, batch_size=hparams[HP_HIDDEN_UNITS], verbose=2)

    return accuracy, model
```

**Run everything - function** -> Basically this is the function that I call to train my model.

```py
def run(run_dir, hparams, version_data_control, optimizer_name, validation_method, callbacks, folder_path):
    with tf.summary.create_file_writer(run_dir).as_default():
        hp.hparams(hparams)  # record the values used in this trial
        accuracy, model = create_fit_keras_model(hparams, version_data_control, optimizer_name, validation_method, callbacks, folder_path)
        print(model.history.history)
        tf.summary.scalar(METRIC_ACCURACY, accuracy, step=1)

    return model
```

**Training process** -> Runs successfully on my local machine but not in Google Colab.

```py
session_num = 1

for batch_size in HP_HIDDEN_UNITS.domain.values:
    for embedding_dim in HP_EMBEDDING_DIM.domain.values:
        for learning_rate in HP_LEARNING_RATE.domain.values:
            for decay_steps_multiplier in HP_DECAY_STEPS_MULTIPLIER.domain.values:
                hparams = {
                    HP_HIDDEN_UNITS: batch_size,
                    HP_EMBEDDING_DIM: embedding_dim,
                    HP_LEARNING_RATE: learning_rate,
                    HP_DECAY_STEPS_MULTIPLIER: decay_steps_multiplier
                  }
                run_name = "run-id {0}/{1}".format(session_num, (len(HP_HIDDEN_UNITS.domain.values)*len(HP_EMBEDDING_DIM.domain.values)*len(HP_LEARNING_RATE.domain.values)*len(HP_DECAY_STEPS_MULTIPLIER.domain.values)))
                print('--- Starting trial: %s/n' % run_name)
                print({h.name: hparams[h] for h in hparams}, "/n")
                
                model_history=run('./logs/hparam_tuning/' + run_name, hparams, version_data_control, "adam", "validation_split",
                                  callback("model_one/adam_v2_07072020", 
                                           "multi_input_keras_model_{0}dim_{1}batchsize_{2}lr_{3}decaymultiplier_{4}".format(str(embedding_dim), str(batch_size), str(learning_rate), str(decay_steps_multiplier), version_data_control),
                                           "./logs/hparam_tuning/"+datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S"), 
                                           hparams),
                                  "model_one/adam_v2_07072020")
                
                hist = pd.DataFrame(model_history.history.history)
                hist['epoch'] = model_history.history.epoch
```

Everything is running fine based on the screenshot below. Although the history model that is returned from the run() function is totally empty. Also, nothing is printed on Tensorboard even though the logs are in the logdir directory. Also, I want to add that the code posted above is perfectly running on my local machine, both Tensorboard and callbacks, and model history. But due to lack of resources, I want to run this on colab for 100 epochs and not 1 as in this example (demo).

*The error I get*
[image]

*My files*
[image]

Thank you in advance for any comments and help. If you may want to see the full code with data I can share with you my colab notebook. Just post in the comments your Gmail account and I will share it with you!

Answer (score 2):

I solved the issue by assigning the model.fit() method to a different object like below:

```py
fitted_model = model.fit([X_train_seq_actors, X_train_seq_plot, X_train_seq_features, X_train_seq_reviews],
                  y_train,
                  steps_per_epoch=int(np.ceil((X_train_seq_actors.shape[0]*optimizer_parameters['validation_split_ratio'])//hparams[HP_HIDDEN_UNITS])),
                  epochs=fit_parameters["epoch"],
                  verbose=fit_parameters["verbose_fit"],
                  batch_size=hparams[HP_HIDDEN_UNITS],
                  validation_split=fit_parameters['validation_data_ratio'],
                  callbacks=callbacks)
```

then by returning the `fitted_model` object I can successfully run this `hist = pd.DataFrame(model_history.history)`

Output:

```
+----+----------+------------+------------+----------------+---------+
|    |     loss |   accuracy |   val_loss |   val_accuracy |   epoch |
|----+----------+------------+------------+----------------+---------|
|  1 | 0.295619 |   0.452375 |   0.186601 |        0.64396 |       1 |
+----+----------+------------+------------+----------------+---------+
```

Hope this will also help other users. Please feel free to assign this as a [Duplicate] question if a similar answer was given on the same issue.

Comment: it is a very weird one. I suddenly faced the similar issue today when I called `model.history.history` returning empty dictionary. So I need to assign separate variable like you suggested and it works.

Comment: @kitokid Happy that I helped you :)